# How to install JCL html2 help in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, jedi

I tried to use the [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) installer to install the html2 help from the [latest-and-greatest JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/JCL%20Releases/JCL%202.3%20Build%204197/), picking the option to integrate it with the DXE2 help, and it broke the DXE2 help: *i.e.* when I started the help viewer in the IDE, it told me that there was no index/table of contents. After some thrashing I was able to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5431744/222450) to restore the DXE2 help, at which point I attempted to install the JCL help manually using h2reg. That appears not to work. I don't see any JCL topics in the contents or index, and when I search for things that I know should be there I find nothing.

Has anyone succeeded in installing this help and getting it integrated with the IDE help in DXE2? If so, how?

Edit to add:
The relevant part of the h2reg log file seems to be this: evidently I am missing a crucial piece: should I be able to build it from the stuff in the JCL help I downloaded?

```
===============================================================================
10:38:34 AM   [Reg_Namespace] - Lines To Process = 1
10:38:34 AM     <nsName>="Jedi.Jcl"
10:38:34 AM     <nsColfile>="C:\VCL\JCL\help\JclVcl_COL_MASTER.HxC"
10:38:34 AM     <nsDesc>="JEDI Code Library VCL package"
10:38:34 AM     +Mode = Not Enabled
10:38:34 AM   ** Reg Error **: Cound not register Namespace: "Jedi.Jcl", because Col file not found "C:\VCL\JCL\help\JclVcl_COL_MASTER.HxC"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:38:34 AM   [Reg_Title] - Lines To Process = 1
10:38:34 AM     <nsName>="Jedi.Jcl"
10:38:34 AM     <TitleID>="JclVcl"
10:38:34 AM     <LangID>=""
10:38:34 AM     <HxS_HelpFile>="C:\VCL\JCL\help\JclVcl.HxS"
10:38:34 AM     <HxI_IndexFile>="C:\VCL\JCL\help\JclVcl.HxI"
10:38:34 AM     <HxQ_QueryFile>=""
10:38:34 AM     <HxR_AttrQueryFile>=""
10:38:34 AM     <HxsMediaLoc>=""
10:38:34 AM     <HxqMediaLoc>=""
10:38:34 AM     <HxrMediaLoc>=""
10:38:34 AM     <SampleMediaLoc>=""
10:38:34 AM   ** Reg Error **: Namespace name not found on this PC "Jedi.Jcl"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does `H2Reg_Log.txt` (in the same folder as `H2Reg.exe` tell you?. (If there's too much noise there, rename it and re-try registering again; it'll create a new file.)