# How to Include Indy help in Delphi10.3?

Tags: indy, delphi-10.3-rio

How can I include the indy helpfiles in windows help for Delphi 10.3 so that it is available on F1 in delphi?

Comment: See [Providing Help for Your Component](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Providing_Help_for_Your_Component) and [How can I manually register an html-help file into the Delphi (RAD Studio) XE6 online documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577532/). Just note that [Indy's help files](https://www.indyproject.org/documentation/) are pretty old, they have not been updated in years.

Comment: Thx @RemyLebeau, where can I find the current documentation then?

Comment: [On the page I linked to earlier](https://www.indyproject.org/documentation/). It provides links to help files and online docs. But as I said, NONE of the documentation has been updated in years. Much of it is still relevant, but there have been changes/updates to Indy since the last time the documentation was touched.

Comment: ok, so there is no uptodate docu. :-)